# custom voice while navigating

Tags: android, navigation, voice

Is there a way to provide different navigation voice files to the android navigation app? (Other than hard solutions of intercepting voice data sent to the sound component on the device)

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate question. The simple answer is no. You could be able to change the speech rate of accent or the underlying tts service (Text to speech), but you cannot change the voice completely. ( There are requirement request posted tho.. so you can wait ;))

Comment: I'm looking for a programming answer. I could not locate the already answered version, link? I assume some of the commands are not TTS, "take a left", is the quality of TTS component that good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single "android navigation app".

AFAIK, all real-time turn-by-turn navigation apps for Android, such as Google Navigation, are closed source and have no APIs. Hence, AFAIK, the answer is "no".